# HTTP2 Push XMLHttpRequest Cache Miss in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caching, xmlhttprequest, http2

I'm setting the Link header to preload an XHR request that happens on load.

```
Link: </images/project_icon.png>; rel=preload; as=image,</db/xhr_stuff>; rel=preload
```

Chrome 57.0 preloads and uses the `/images/project_icon.png` just fine but it preloads `/db/xhr_stuff` and then misses the copy it just retrieved and loads it a second time after the DOM completely loads. The request headers are identical except the one later one initiated by the xhr has `x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest` set. The only other difference between the requests is the one initiated by the link header shows up as `Type: json` and the second `Type: xhr` in the Developer Tools.

According to the docs for XHR request, you just omit the `as=` attribute.

What is missing to get a cache hit?

Comment: I'm curious, did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide the "as=" attribute when you push it will be ignored by the page and loaded again.

> According to the docs for XHR request, you just omit the as= attribute.

Where do you see this? What "docs"?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/ 

`XHR, fetch <link rel=preload href=...>`

Comment: Did you try `as "fetch" crossorigin` as suggested by that link?